# Is it normal to feel very tired, nauseous a few minutes after a workout?

Tags: energy, hydration, post-workout

I find that when I really push myself, my body doesn't reward me.

This occurs usually only when I am doing upper body workouts.

I feel like I am pushing myself and I can really feel my arms burn. When this happens, I sometimes decide to cut my workout 1 or 2 sets short because, even though mentally I feel I can do it, which makes me want to do it for the sake of pushing myself, I have had enough of these experiences that I know to stop anyways.

Then, about 1-2 minutes later, when I sit down and drink some water, I am thanking my lucky stars that I didn't do it, because I feel ridiculously tired and nauseous for 5-15 mins.

Is this normal or am I dehydrated or something?

Why is it that I feel like I can do anything as I am contemplating it, but its only afterwards that my workout catches up to me.

Feel free to tell me if I'm just being a b**** and it's normal. I just don't want to inadvertently hurt myself as a result of trying to become strong.

Comment: Its been about a month since I posted this. I have been making sure to drink more water and eat more and as time goes on, the issue isn't as bad now. I know my limits now though and can more confidently push them safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling tired and nauseated after a workout [is normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercise-induced_nausea), especially if you've been pushing yourself. You've likely burned through a lot of energy reserves, and your adrenaline will be crashing. If it happens every time, even after light workouts, I'd recommend seeing a doctor, just in case there's something wrong, maybe an endocrine issue.

As regards the nausea, after a very intensive workout, [your body has been routing blood to the more important exercising bits](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/questions/qotw/question/1000148/), so your stomach will be a bit queasy for a time. It's natural.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say what the reasons for your problems are. It is impossible to give personal correct answer without knowing you.

But I can give you some advices which helped me:

1. Eat and drink enough before you start your training, if you have too little energy it is like going through hell.
2. Your Training has to be suitable for yourself, if you are a beginner you can't perform the training of an olympic athlete.
3. Training, especially strength training is a very hard training and especially at the beginning it is important to never give up.

I hope I could at least help you a little bit.